# How to share this variable between modules?

Tags: angular

I am trying to share a variable between two modules. Basically what I'm trying to do is share a username from the login component (from the home module) with a profile module, so the profile screen shows the username of the logged in user.

[image: Profile screen right now]

On the picture above, the username is supposed to go on where the red "USERNAME" is (that red text is NOT from code, I just added that text to the picture to visualize what I mean)

So basically what I tried is as follows. In my profile.ts I made a variable "username" and a method "setUsername" where I set the "username" variable to whatever is passed through the "setUsername" parameter. This is my profile.ts from the profile module:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from 'src/app/home/services/login.service';
import { HomeLoginComponent } from '../../home/components/home-login.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'profile.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(){}
    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    username: string;

    setUsername(username: string)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

In the logincomponent.ts, from the module home, whenever a user gets logged in and the login details are correct, before I log in (using the Login() method) I pass the element.email to the "setUsername()" method in the profile.ts.

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UserStoreService } from '../../core/User-store.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginautenthicationService } from '../services/loginautenthication.service';
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { textChangeRangeIsUnchanged } from 'typescript';
import { UserModel } from '../../user/models/user.model';
import { ProfileComponent } from '../../profile/components/profile.component';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'home-login.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class HomeLoginComponent implements OnInit{

    email = '';
    wachtwoord = '';
    userarr: UserModel[];
   
    constructor(private userStoreService: UserStoreService, private router: Router, private loginauthenticationService: LoginautenthicationService, private loginService: LoginService, private profile: ProfileComponent) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loginService.getUsers().subscribe(
            (users: UserModel[]) => this.userarr = users
        );
       
    }

    Submit()
    {   
        this.userarr.forEach(element => {
            if(this.email === element.email && this.wachtwoord === element.wachtwoord)
            {
                this.profile.setUsername(element.email);
                this.loginauthenticationService.Authenticate(true);
                this.userStoreService.Login();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Also in the HTML file of the profile.ts I use this, so the username shows up:

```
<h5 class="title h-100 row justify-content-center">{{username}}</h5>
```

So, why doesn't anything show up? What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

EDIT: I just noticed the variable email that I try to pass is undefined for some reason. Which is weird, because the my Submit() method works to log the user in, but then it is undefined?

Comment: I didn't came with an answer, but just wanted to warn you that looping over users and matching passwords means that people can see all your users passwords in the browser. You should do this kind of matching in the backend..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you getting this message in console: 'NullInjectorError: No provider for ProfileComponent!' ?

Because you can't add a component in a constructor, you have to add a Service.

So create a service, for example ProfileService

```
    ng g s profile
```

There you have your username and setter.
This service should be injected in the constructor of HomeComponent and ProfileComponent

Now HomeComponent can set the username and ProfileComponent can show it in html.
The idea here is a shared service, which is the way to go in your case..

EDIT:
Here is a working example:

profile.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ProfileService {
    
      constructor() { }
    
      userNameSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
    
      public setUsername(username: string)
      {
          this.userNameSubject.next(username);
      }
    }
```

profile.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ProfileService } from '../profile.service';
    import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-profile',
      templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
    })
    export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    
      username: Observable<string>;
    
      constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) {
        this.username = this.profileService.userNameSubject.pipe(share());
      }
    
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    
    }
```

profile.component.html:

```
    <p>
      Username: {{username | async}}
    </p>
```

home.component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ProfileService } from '../profile.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    
      submit(){
        this.profileService.setUsername('TestUserEmail');
      }
    
    }
```

home.component.html:

```
    <button (click)="submit()">Click here</button>
```

app.component.html:

```
    <app-profile></app-profile>
    <app-home></app-home>
```

Comment: You're welcome, posted an example in the edit in the meanwhile. But if it already works, then you can ignore :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have several options of hiw components can communicate with eachother: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
I suppose you to use via service way